# Change the location of the QTabBar holding QDockWidgets?

Tags: qt

I have a QMainWindow with several QDockWidgets all in the same area, which forces the dock widgets to be tabbed in a QTabBar. The tabs appear at the bottom left corner of the dock area. (In the screenshot the tabs are named "Properties", "Resources", "Attribute Editor", and "Operations".)

Is is possible change where the tabs are located relative to the dock widgets? Specifically, can the tabs be placed above the dock widgets instead of below them?

[image: Dock widget tabs below the dock widgets. Can they be moved above the dock widgets?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QMainWindow::setTabPosition()` method ([Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setTabPosition)).

```
// Will display the tab above the docked widgets in the left side
mainWindow->setTabPosition(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, QTabWidget::North);
```